# How to compare image under UV light from normal light on iPhone?

Tags: ios, image, image-processing, camera

The purpose is to find things that only react to UV light, by capturing 2 images from camera, one under normal light and one under the same normal light mixed with an UV light source.

My initial intuition is to compare the 2 pictures pixel by pixel, and find a range of normal differences for "normal" stuff between the 2 light sources, and then get pixels that are abruptly beyond the range to assert they only react to UV light. However, I don't have good knowledge in how images work under different light sources and couldn't find relevant answers, so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I think first you need match the position,rotation,skew of the two images so they match, then substract the images and then derive the result to emphasize the differences and eliminate the constant illumination bias a bit. Also illumination normalization could improve results, without seeing the input images is hard to answer sometimes RGB other times HSV is better ... this time may be the BLUE channel will be enough but I might be wrong ...

Comment: Thanks @Spektre! They should be taken one instantly after another, so position & rotation should be exactly the same. I haven't seen the input images either but want to get some general ideas first; will add images whenever I can. Would gray-scaled version be easier to compare? Will it lose useful information in this case?

Comment: unless you have high end stative and very short time between shots or very low resolution then the images can be off by few pixels even on mounted setup. I think if you use Blue channel (not gray scale) it should be enough because blue band is the closest to UV but if your scene surfaces have features like fluorescence then all bands are needed

Comment: Interesting - didn't know that and I'm glad I asked here ;) Are there some kind of standard algorithms to help align the pictures? If there is a rotation between the 2 pictures, I'd imagine it's hard to align up

Comment: find few points of interest and cross match them. point of interest is a point with specific feature like local min/max of 2D intensity gradient etc. then create SIFT or similar list of features per each point and match the closest matches between images. when found at least 3 points matched in booth images then construct transform matrix to align the coordinate systems and transform one image to another one ... that is it in a nutshell. to be more specific I need to see the actual input data you have or have background knowledge on your task, without it is unlikely anyone try to answer

Comment: I am not expert in this field (done just few projects and from that only few comercial) but for common algorithms you can look into 3D stereoscopy (for the align) and for SIFT extraction and matching (for the rest)

Comment: Thanks again @Spektre! It turns out the UV source will be presented at an arbitrary positions, thus there will be shadow generated from that source as well... So I feel I'll not dig further into it for the moment. However, your explanation of the 3 point matching approach is really eye-opening for me. Lesson learned :)